# R + jupyter tapply() function gives `Error: subscript out of bounds`

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have this minimal code in an R - Jupyter notebook:

```
In[1]:
    a = c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 )
    b = c( 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0 )
   print( tapply( a, b, mean ) )
```

which gives this output:

```
    0 1 2 3 
    6 2 4 5
```

If I just run a cell with:

```
In[2]: 
    tapply( a, b, mean )
```

I get this output (in that order):

```
Error in dn[[2L]]: subscript out of bounds    

Out[2]:
    0    6
    1    2
    2    4
    3    5
```

Interestingly, the following does not throw an error:

```
In[3]:
    t( tapply( a, b, mean ) )
Out[3]:
    0 1 2 3
    6 2 4 5
```

---

Why do I get this error?

And why does it print *vertically*?

And why don't I get the labels `Out[]` when using `print()`?

It seems that it has something to do with how Jupyter prints the value of objects when called with no `print()` function... And something about the Notice that the calculation itself is correct, so the error doesn't appear to be harmful, it's just strange :P

**Note:** The error doesn't occur in bash, nor in rStudio, only in Jupyter.

Comment: I get no error. Try in a fresh R session?

Comment: No error here either.

Comment: Tested again in bash and rstudio, it doesn't give error there. It only gives the error message in a jupyter notebook. Updated the question, just for curiosity, since the calculation is correct.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens indeed in jupyter-notebook but not in Rstudio. Any idea?